# Web-RTC: Connecting to a remote server

Tags: server, client-server, webrtc

I'm trying to implement a simple Web RTC App as shown in [Building a WebRTC Video Chat Application with PeerJS](https://www.sitepoint.com/webrtc-video-chat-application-peerjs/) which uses the code from [here](https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/peer-messenger). It works when I use the application on my computer opening to browser tabs, one for the initiator and one for the receiver. But how can I connect to a server running on a friend of mine's machine, perhaps at his home, on a different network? We tried launching the server and the client from his machine and the client from mine and then having him connecting on Chrome to http://localhost:3000 as the guide suggests while I typed on Chrome his public IP address followed by port 80, but it doesn't work.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

the signaling server should be running on the public internet, see [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/)
WebRTC lets the browsers connect directly to each other and exchange media and data, you still need a way for them to do the initial connection.

Comment: In the article you linked I found this: https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab which is a good explaination of Web RTC but still works only connecting to localhost. How a peer from another computer and possibly another network can connect to the server?